# Can I play Plasma on the MacBook Air M1 base model?

Tags: gaming, macbook

Can I play [Plasma](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1409160/Plasma/) on the MacBook Air M1 base model?
Maybe using Parallels? The requirements mention GPU. But there is a GPU in the MacBook Air M1 base model. Could it run the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an example of somebody playing Plasma this way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI2KY4ZOenM

I think the developers of Plasma mentioned that there may be a Mac version too later.